# Completely remove refline in scrlttr2

Tags: koma-script, letters

I want to use KOMA variables like `myref` but I do not want the `refline` to appear in my document (as I intend to put the `myref` somewhere else).  However, `refline=false` seems to have no effect.  How can I make the refline totally disappear?

MWE (without the refline disappearing):

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\setkomavar{myref}{letterone}
%\KOMAoptions{refline=false} %%This does NOT WORK
\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Mrs Mabel Canary\\24 The Street\\Some Village\\
Some Town\\Noshire\\AB1 2YZ}
  \opening{Dear Mrs~Canary}

  This is an imaginary letter.

  This is the second paragraph of the letter.

  \closing{Yours sincerely}

  \ps PS: this is a postscript.

  \encl{Photocopy of something interesting\\
   Photocopy of something rather dull}

  \cc{Prof Important Person\\
   Dr Bor Ing}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `\removereffields` to remove all fields from the refline except the date:

```latex
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\setkomavar{myref}{letterone}
\removereffields% <- added

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Mrs Mabel Canary\\24 The Street\\Some Village\\
Some Town\\Noshire\\AB1 2YZ}
  \opening{Dear Mrs~Canary}

  This is an imaginary letter.

  This is the second paragraph of the letter.

  \closing{Yours sincerely}

  \ps PS: this is a postscript.

  \encl{Photocopy of something interesting\\
   Photocopy of something rather dull}

  \cc{Prof Important Person\\
   Dr Bor Ing}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

[image]